# Toggle value not passed in url as a parameter

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm using toggle button for selecting one value from the two:

```
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" name="gender_type" {{ gender_type=="male" ? "checked":"" }}><div class="slider round">
<span class="on">Male</span>
<span class="off">Female</span>
</div></label>
```

By default on page load one value should be checked based on gender_type and the value of checkbox is not passed as a url parameter when i submit the form.

Comment: isn't this angular template code? If so I don't understand the jquery question tag. Note that a checkbox value is passed only when checked, this is how you can know if it has been checked or not (present or not)

Comment: @Kaddath: No its simple html, but i want to pass both values what's the solution, if not  ON how can i get another value

Comment: You can use the form's `onsubmit` and add the data manually, or add a hidden input on the checkbox's `onchange`. But just testing if the value is here in `$_GET / $_POST` in PHP should work allright